# How to calculate Order status Report in Azure NoSQL CosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We are using Azure NOSQL cosmosDB. We have a order container in it. One of the property in this container is order status.

Order status can be like InCart, Initiated, SubmittedUnPaid, PaymentInPogress, PaymentFailed, Paid, Rejected, PartiallyRejected, DeliveryInProgress, Delivered, UnDelivered, SuccessClosed etc..

I need a report for my senior management where they have report filter start date - end date means they want to see Order Status wise report between any 2 dates. Start and end date can be in different years as well say 10/May/2021 - 17/Aug/2023.

This report will be displayed as a web page on our web application so delay or report display should not be say 10 seconds. Hope you understand report should render as soon as possible. What is the best way to generate such report.  I am thinking of Batch job as well but not sure about what query i should write? I am ok to use Azure Synapse as well if required.

i feel this should be a batch job but not sure what should be my query be like?

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL server and mysql then? They are totally different rdbms

Comment: I removed all of your extra tags, as this has nothing to do with them. Aside from that: this question is off-topic as written: it's really not possible to give you an objective answer to "how to create a report" - how you do this, and what reporting tool you choose, is up to you. This will also be highly dependent on the shape of your data (e.g. document schema, various containers, etc). This could involve materialized views or something else.

Comment: In general, opinion-based questions, and recommendation-based questions, are off topic here (and this question ticks both boxes, aside from this not being a programming question)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few good approaches to create real-time reports from Azure Cosmos DB using REST API on a web app:

- Call the Cosmos DB REST API from your web app to query the data. The REST API allows you to perform CRUD operations and run SQL queries to retrieve data.
- On the web app, query the Cosmos DB in real-time when the page loads or user takes an action. Display the results in a chart/table using a framework like Chart.js.
- Use Azure Functions with Cosmos DB trigger. Trigger the function on create/update events in Cosmos collections. Function can process new data and update a dashboard.
- Maintain a materialized view of the reports/aggregates in a separate Cosmos collection. Update it using a background scheduled Function that runs periodically. Query this view for real-time reports.
- Use Change Feed Processor library in web app to listen to changes to Cosmos collections. Process new docs to update real-time views.
- Perform computations on inserted/modified docs during Cosmos DB triggers. Output results to a reporting collection queried by the web app.
- Use Cosmos DB analytical store to run aggregates on live data. Query analytical store from the web app to show reports.

Comment: Ok but this doesn’t answer any specific programming question. It’s just a list of ideas and services. The OP has provided no specific programming question or detail (or anything else aside from a high level description).

Comment: Also honestly this seems like a ChatGPT-generated answer: nobody would be suggesting using the REST API as a reporting approach, and Azure functions / web apps are just ways of running code.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, In the question along with code it was also asked about approach (batch or ..) and services (synapse or ..). My answer was about approach and services. If my answer is providing partial solution that doesn't mean it is not useful. All the approaches are the possible options, I have not recommended any of them. About the reporting on web question itself says 'This report will be displayed as a web page'. On your assumption of ChatGPT generated answer, I will not stop you from assuming things, but it would be better if we start looking for positives.

Comment: Its an event data. @KuldeepSingh are you saying real time data processing is the only way? Batch approach will not work here? It is typical e-commerce problem statement.  This is how most e commerce team generating there reports?

Comment: @know1995 you can also process your result in batch, but you mentioned that your report should not be delayed more than 10 seconds, is that right? In that case your batch needs to be processed every 10 seconds. Please accept the answer if helpful in anyway.